# How to keep an Android App logged in indefinitely with Spring Boot Server?

Tags: android, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Ok, To be honest, that headline is a bit misleading but I couldn't think of better one.

I have a Spring Boot based Server and an Android App. The user is authenticated with a username and password and is then provided with a JWT authentication token which is then used in subsequent requests to access the APIs. The token is valid for an hour after which, the user logs in again with his credentials which is inconvenient for user. In fact, I need the application to ask for credentials again only if the user explicitly logs out of the app.

I think using a refresh token is the answer to this but I am not sure how to implement it in my current code?

**AuthController's authenticate method**

```
@PostMapping("/signin")
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    loginRequest.getUsernameOrEmail(),
                    loginRequest.getPassword()
            )
    );

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    String jwt = tokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(jwt));
}
```

**JwtAuthenticationResponse**

```
public class JwtAuthenticationResponse {
    private String accessToken;
    private String refreshToken = "Blank";
    private String tokenType = "Bearer";

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

**JwtTokenProvider**

```
@Component
 public class JwtTokenProvider {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtTokenProvider.class);

@Value("${app.jwtSecret}")
private String jwtSecret;

@Value("${app.jwtExpirationInMs}")
private int jwtExpirationInMs;

public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {

    UserPrincipal userDetails = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();

    Date now = new Date();
    Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + jwtExpirationInMs);

    return Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(Long.toString(userDetails.getId()))
            .setIssuedAt(new Date())
            .setExpiration(expiryDate)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
            .compact();
}

public Long getUserIdFromJWT(String token) {
    Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
            .setSigningKey(jwtSecret)
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody();

    return Long.parseLong(claims.getSubject());
}

public boolean validateToken(String authToken) {
    try {
        Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
        return true;
    } catch (SignatureException ex) {
        logger.error("Invalid JWT signature");
    } catch (MalformedJwtException ex) {
        logger.error("Invalid JWT token");
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
        logger.error("Expired JWT token");
    } catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex) {
        logger.error("Unsupported JWT token");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        logger.error("JWT claims string is empty.");
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

I understand that I'll need another method to create a JWT refresh token in **JwtTokenProvider** which I could call from **authenticateUser** method in the **AuthController**. That refresh token will be sent back by the Android Application after the **accessToken** expires to get a new **accessToken**. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a refresh token while generating the access token and persist in the database against that user. Here are the code changes that you need to do -

**JwtRefreshToken Model**

Create a JwtRefreshToken domain model:

```
package com.example.polls.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.Instant;

@Entity
@Table(name = "refresh_tokens")
public class JwtRefreshToken {
    @Id
    private String token;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    private Instant expirationDateTime;

    public JwtRefreshToken() {

    }

    public JwtRefreshToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Instant getExpirationDateTime() {
        return expirationDateTime;
    }

    public void setExpirationDateTime(Instant expirationDateTime) {
        this.expirationDateTime = expirationDateTime;
    }
}
```

**JwtRefreshToken repository**

Create the repository for accessing the RefreshToken:

```
package com.example.polls.repository;

import com.example.polls.model.JwtRefreshToken;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface JwtRefreshTokenRepository extends JpaRepository<JwtRefreshToken, String> {

}
```

**JwtAuthenticationResponse**

Add refreshToken and expiresInMsec fields to the Authentication response:

```
package com.example.polls.payload;

/**
 * Created by rajeevkumarsingh on 19/08/17.
 */
public class JwtAuthenticationResponse {
    private String accessToken;
    private String refreshToken;
    private String tokenType = "Bearer";
    private Long expiresInMsec;

    public JwtAuthenticationResponse(String accessToken, String refreshToken, Long expiresInMsec) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
        this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        this.expiresInMsec = expiresInMsec;
    }

    public String getRefreshToken() {
        return refreshToken;
    }

    public void setRefreshToken(String refreshToken) {
        this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
    }

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    public String getTokenType() {
        return tokenType;
    }

    public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
        this.tokenType = tokenType;
    }

    public Long getExpiresInMsec() {
        return expiresInMsec;
    }

    public void setExpiresInMsec(Long expiresInMsec) {
        this.expiresInMsec = expiresInMsec;
    }
}
```

**JwtTokenProvider**

Add method to generate a refresh token:

```
package com.example.polls.security;

import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtTokenProvider.class);

    @Value("${app.jwtSecret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${app.jwtExpirationInMs}")
    private long jwtExpirationInMs;

    public String generateToken(UserPrincipal userPrincipal) {
        Date now = new Date();
        Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + jwtExpirationInMs);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(Long.toString(userPrincipal.getId()))
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(expiryDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                .compact();
    }

    public String generateRefreshToken() {
        // generate a random UUID as refresh token
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public Long getUserIdFromJWT(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(jwtSecret)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();

        return Long.parseLong(claims.getSubject());
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException ex) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature");
        } catch (MalformedJwtException ex) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            logger.error("Expired JWT token");
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex) {
            logger.error("Unsupported JWT token");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty.");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**AuthController**

Persist the refresh token and write the API to refresh access tokens:

```
package com.example.polls.controller;

import com.example.polls.exception.AppException;
import com.example.polls.exception.BadRequestException;
import com.example.polls.model.JwtRefreshToken;
import com.example.polls.model.Role;
import com.example.polls.model.RoleName;
import com.example.polls.model.User;
import com.example.polls.payload.*;
import com.example.polls.repository.JwtRefreshTokenRepository;
import com.example.polls.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.example.polls.repository.UserRepository;
import com.example.polls.security.JwtTokenProvider;
import com.example.polls.security.UserPrincipal;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.net.URI;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 * Created by rajeevkumarsingh on 02/08/17.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    JwtRefreshTokenRepository jwtRefreshTokenRepository;

    @Value("${app.jwtExpirationInMs}")
    private long jwtExpirationInMs;

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginRequest.getUsernameOrEmail(),
                        loginRequest.getPassword()
                )
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();

        String accessToken = tokenProvider.generateToken(userPrincipal);
        String refreshToken = tokenProvider.generateRefreshToken();

        saveRefreshToken(userPrincipal, refreshToken);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(accessToken, refreshToken, jwtExpirationInMs));
    }

    @PostMapping("/refreshToken")
    public ResponseEntity<?> refreshAccessToken(@Valid @RequestBody RefreshTokenRequest refreshTokenRequest) {
        return jwtRefreshTokenRepository.findById(refreshTokenRequest.getRefreshToken()).map(jwtRefreshToken -> {
            User user = jwtRefreshToken.getUser();
            String accessToken = tokenProvider.generateToken(UserPrincipal.create(user));
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(accessToken, jwtRefreshToken.getToken(), jwtExpirationInMs));
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new BadRequestException("Invalid Refresh Token"));
    }

    private void saveRefreshToken(UserPrincipal userPrincipal, String refreshToken) {
        // Persist Refresh Token

        JwtRefreshToken jwtRefreshToken = new JwtRefreshToken(refreshToken);
        jwtRefreshToken.setUser(userRepository.getOne(userPrincipal.getId()));

        Instant expirationDateTime = Instant.now().plus(360, ChronoUnit.DAYS);  // Todo Add this in application.properties
        jwtRefreshToken.setExpirationDateTime(expirationDateTime);

        jwtRefreshTokenRepository.save(jwtRefreshToken);
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {
        if(userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
            return new ResponseEntity(new ApiResponse(false, "Username is already taken!"),
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        if(userRepository.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail())) {
            return new ResponseEntity(new ApiResponse(false, "Email Address already in use!"),
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        // Creating user's account
        User user = new User(signUpRequest.getName(), signUpRequest.getUsername(),
                signUpRequest.getEmail(), signUpRequest.getPassword());

        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.ROLE_USER)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new AppException("User Role not set."));

        user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(userRole));

        User result = userRepository.save(user);

        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                .fromCurrentContextPath().path("/users/{username}")
                .buildAndExpand(result.getUsername()).toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.created(location).body(new ApiResponse(true, "User registered successfully"));
    }
}
```

**RefreshTokenRequest**

This is used by the /api/auth/refreshToken API.

```
package com.example.polls.payload;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

public class RefreshTokenRequest {
    @NotBlank
    private String refreshToken;

    public String getRefreshToken() {
        return refreshToken;
    }

    public void setRefreshToken(String refreshToken) {
        this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll also need to delete the refresh token from the database on logout. I haven't supplied the code for that but I think that should be trivial to implement.

You can find all the code in the **refresh-token** branch of this [Github repository](https://github.com/callicoder/spring-security-react-ant-design-polls-app/tree/refresh-token)

Comment: I have three points to mention:
1. If he is logged out then still I have session for the same user since token is still not expired. 
2. When will you hit `/refreshToken` how will your reactjs app will know that token has been expired now hit backend and suppose in failed response if I hit the api to get the token back imagine anybody can keep on hitting our api and keep checking data from db again and again.
3. Storing in db is not good option therefore redis or memcache or apache ignite is good in this case. Actually